# Disabling Web camera

Tags: debian, security, camera

My Eee PC comes with a Web cam, which I never use. How can I ensure that it is effectively disabled, so that no software can use it?

Comment: Nothing in software will make you as sure as a bit of opaque tape stuck over it.

Comment: @Ulrich Schwarz: A sticker works quite as well, plus people don't look at you as if you're wearing a tin-foil hat ;)

Comment: Related: [Can webcams be turned on without the indicator light?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/6758)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`modprobe -r uvcvideo` should remove the webcam module temporarily (without the need for reboot). You can add that to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` to make it permenant. Please check whether the above command works before adding.

uvcvideo is the module for my Linux. Yours could be different. Try running `lsmod | grep uvcv` if you face any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Add

```
blacklist uvcvideo
```

at the bottom. Save the file and quit the text editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the kernel drive module responsible for it, which is most cases is `uvcvideo`. The `modprobe` let's you enable and disable kernel module, therefore, you can disable your webcam like so:

```
modprobe -r uvcvideo
```

And enable it again like this:

```
modprobe uvcvideo
```

You can also check whether or not the module is actually disable looking for it using `lsmod`, which shows the status of modules in the kernel.

```
lsmod | grep uvcvideo
```

The output should be similar to this when the module is enabled:

```
uvcvideo               98304  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       49152  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
videodev              225280  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
mc                     53248  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
```

And when it is disabled no occurrences to `uvcvideo` should be returned from the command.