# disable microphone and camera for a user

Tags: systemd, group, camera, microphone

Is there a simple way to denied access to camera and microphone to specific user?

A solution using as shown here [Disabling Web camera](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32364/disabling-web-camera) is not really suitable as other users need to renable-it via sudo command.

So far I didn't find any solution to really specify which user can and which user cannot.

UPDATE:

- I am running Manjaro/Arch
- Seems that could be related to `systemd` https://wiki.archlinux.or/index.php/Users_and_groups#Pre-systemd_groups
- `getent group video` > `video:x:986:`
- none of my user is under `video` group
- targeted user is only under is own group `groups my-user` -> `my-user`
- `my-user` has access to video capture `/dev/video0` tested with VLC

Comment: I believe that the accepted answer in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141255/give-a-specific-user-permissions-to-a-device-without-giving-access-to-other-user is valid for your case, too

Comment: `udev` rule sounds as good direction. But still a bit obscure.

Answer (score 0):

On my debian, camera device file is `/dev/video0` and permissions are the following:

```
$ ls -l /dev/video0 
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Nov 18 16:54 /dev/video0
```

My user is in part group `video` so that i can use the webcam... but if it wasn't, i wouldn't be able to.
So just remove the user from group `video` (or the equivalent on your system) to disable the ability to use webcam.

Comment: none of my users are part of `video` group. I am running a Manjaro/Arch. And I believe that is due to `systemd` https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Users_and_groups#Pre-systemd_groups

Comment: nothing stops you in adding users to a group. And even assigning a new group to a device which then eligible users are made part of. This kind of stuff is exactly one of the reasons to have (different) groups

Comment: I want don't want to grant access but to forbid access. @planetmaker I don't get how adding a group to camera device and adding user to will stop a specific user to use it.

Comment: Yes, so? Have all users be in that group except those which you want to deny usage...

Comment: still there not any users in the `video` group and everyone has access. So adding users to `video` changes nothing.

Comment: @mickro Everything seems explained in the documentation you linked: if your system run `systemd`, then, permissions are not managed this way anymore but with ACL and systemd-login.... Look to this direction